# php & css best way to create a theme with custom colors

Tags: php, css, templates, colors, themes

I just created a CSS theme for my user's panel

Now I have to add to the CSS some PHP variables that the users can change in their panel to customize the main colors of the theme.

I have found 3 way but both have cons...

**Way 1: overwrite CSS proprieties with inline style**

Cons: many many classes to overwrite and print in the head of the document

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/default.css"> 
<style>
.class1 { background: <?php echo $color1; ?>; } 
.class2 { color: <?php echo $color2; ?>; }
```

**Way 2: dinamic file style.php instead of style.css**

Cons: load twice all the php files like config.php connect.php, etc.. AND NO CACHE!

```
<?php // include files  config.php, connect.php, etc.. and read vars from DB
header( 'Content-type: text/css' ); ?>
.class1 { background: <?php echo $color1; ?>; }
```

**Way 3: write a new css file with php every time the users change the colors**

Cons: At every update of the main css i have to update the CSS code in the php script too and existing css files.

```
<?php fwrite( $filename, $css_code); ?>
```

**So what is the best way to implement this PHP vars in my CSS theme? (without SCSS)**

Comment: Can the user choose from a list or can he use each color?

Comment: each color, with a color picker

Comment: You could have some dynamically build your CSS the first time after the changes are made, then if there are ever any changes, you could dynamically update only those parts of the file.

Comment: did you ever come up with an answer for this? I'm looking to do the same. Default theme with customizable color options picked from a color picker. I was thinking of inlining the CSS and overwriting values with PHP but there should be a better way.

Comment: I choosed the second method